# char* losing data

Tags: c++, c, pointers, string

I'm writing a C++ code with returns some data, the problem is: my const char is losing it value each time I call it from another file. I don't have idea what's happening.

My code on ProcClient.h

```
virtual void reportWorkflowError(unsigned int workflow,
        const dp::String& errorCode) {
    char message[1000];
    snprintf(message, 1000, "Workflow: %s ERROR: %s", workflowToString(
            workflow).utf8(), errorCode.utf8());
    printf("[%s]", message);

    errorInfo = message;
}
virtual const char * getErrorInfo() {
    return errorInfo;
}
```

[Workflow: DW_FULFILL ERROR: E_ADEPT_NO_TOKEN]

[Workflow:  ERROR: E_ADEPT_NOT_READY]

//two errors was thrown, and the errorInfo should has the last

On Services.cpp I start a "workflow", and if it throws an error the listener above is called, and after that I should get tha lastError pointer.

//g_drmClient is the ProcClient

```
bool RMServices::startFullfilment(dp::String acsm) {
    //Do things 
g_drmClient->getProcessor()->startWorkflows(dpdrm::DW_FULFILL);
size_t count = g_drmClient->getProcessor()->getFulfillmentItems();
printf("Number of items fulfilled: %d\n", count);

bool returnValue = !g_drmClient->hasError();
if (!returnValue)
    lastError = g_drmClient->getErrorInfo());

printf("[%s]", lastError);

return returnValue;
}
```

Here it prints:
[\æ¾°Ô¯£ ¯|æ¾\æ¾er of items fulfer of ite]

What's happening?

Comment: Tip: try to create a minimal test case which demonstrates the problem. Remove as much code as you can, and it will be much easier for you (and others) to spot the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char message[1000];
```

is a local variable residing on stack and goes out of scope on return of `reportWorkflowError`. So,

```
errorInfo = message; // errorInfo is simply pointing to garbage on method return.
```

---

Do some thing on these lines -

```
void className::foo()
{
    char stackVariable[] = "abcdef" ;
    classVariableCharPointer = new char[ sizeof(stackVariable) + 1 ] ;

    strcpy( classVariableCharPointer, stackVariable ) ;
}
```

Also remember to deallocate the `classVariableCharPointer` in the destructor using `delete[]`.

Comment: use `std::string`? allocate that var with `new[]` (be careful with leaks)? make it an instance variable? plenty of options.

Comment: Thanks. I solved by initializing the errorInfo var and printing on it. errorInfo = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);

Comment: @Marcos - Suggested a model solution. Since it is `C++`, use `new` rather than `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes, you can't do that.

As soon as `reportWorkflowError` returns, all local variables are destroyed. This includes `message`, which `returnValue` points to.

A better approach would include making `returnValue` a character array, and calling `srtrcpy()` to copy the local data to the member variable. This way, the copy would still exist after `message` is destroyed.

Comment: Actually, the reportWorkflowError is from my superclass I cannot change it to return something.

Comment: @Marcos: Then add a new member that is outside of any method in your derived class, copy your data to that, and return a pointer to it. Either way, you cannot setup a pointer to data that will be destroyed as soon as the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting `message` on the stack.  Maybe you want it to be `static`, or better an instance variable.

Comment: Making it a static variable would cause it to overwrite values from other instances of the class. Just make it a class variable.

Comment: @Jonathan: yeh, thinko ("MOAR COFFEE!").  Fixed.